# Testing webservice with LoadRunner/Performance Center

Tags: c, web-services, soap, performance-testing, loadrunner

I have the following code in the **action()** in **Action.C** As it is shown I have parameterised the username in the user registration. I kept the `parameter type` as `Iteration Number` and `text format` as `user%d`(eg. user1 etc.,). In the `runtime settings` I kept `number of iterations` as 500. When I run it locally from vusergenerator it works fine, it creates 500 users(user1, user2 and so on) and then stops. But when I run it from performance center by selecting 30 vusers and 2 load generators, the script misbehaves. Like it runs until I manually stop the run and it keeps giving me errors like it tries to create the same user which is not allowed in the application, so the application throws user already exists error. **Can someone please guide me how to resolve this issue?** Ideally the iteration number should be taken globally by all the 30 vusers(threads), isn't it? So that each thread creates unique user until 500 iterations.

```
Action()
{
    web_service_call("StepName=registerUser_91",
        "SOAPMethod=ComRegisterSvc|ComRegisterSvcBinding|registerUser",
        "ResponseParam=response",
        "Service=ComRegisterSvc",
        "URL=http://company.com/registersvc
        "ExpectedResponse=SoapResult",
        "Snapshot=t1446039143.inf",
        BEGIN_ARGUMENTS,
        "xml:userContextDetails="
            "<userContextDetails>"
                "<userNameId>"
                    "<userName>{DynamicUser}</userName>"
                "</userNameId>"
                 "<firstName>{DynamicUser}</firstName>"
                 "<lastName>{DynamicUser}</lastName>"
            "</userContextDetails>",
        END_ARGUMENTS,
        BEGIN_RESULT,
        END_RESULT,
        LAST);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iteration number is unique for each VUser only.Here in your case you are running with 30 users obviously the iteration number will be duplicated.

You can use parameter type as "unique number" to resolve duplication.

Comment: Okay, I will use unique number, but what is the iteration number that I should keep in runtime settings in order to create 1000 users? And later it should stop the run.

Comment: you have to set "run until completion" in runtime settings ,and set "Number of Iterations" to 1000/30(as are running with 30 users)as you need to create 1000 users.

Comment: While selecting unique number, what is the Block Size Per VUser that I should give and can you please explain the purpose of this?

Comment: Go through  http://www.perftesting.co.uk/different-types-of-loadrunner-parameters/2012/01/01/  http://sqa.fyicenter.com/LoadRunner_Vuser_Scripts/93_Unique_Number.html

Comment: Thanks, I am testing it with the inputs that you have given.

Comment: Can you please let me know which language is suitable for performance center to write actions. I am actually comfortable with java, but it's by default creating action.c

Comment: It supports C language alone for webservices protocol

Comment: How can we declare global variable in C and then use it to concatenate with other strings in action method? Please help me with this last question. As you said I kept as uniquenumber in place of dynamicuser variable, but I want to declare string globally and then use it as user prefix at multiple places.

Comment: you can declare in globals.h

Comment: I declared it like this char userPrefix[] = "UserName"; after global variables comment, in code I kept {userPrefix}, but it's not fetching the value UserName. Please suggest. Am I using in a wrong way?

Comment: No need to define a variable you can use as User{userPrefix}

Comment: Sorry to bug you :( I think I didn't explain my question well, here is scenario <userName>{userPrefix}{IterationNum}</userName>, so I need to use this userPrefix value at multiple locations in multiple places in code. However the value will not be changed anywhere in code, it's a constant whose value is used at multiple places. So, I want to declare and assign a value to this globally. can you please tell me how to achieve this?